# Getting the amount of images which are in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, image

I'm trying to get the amount of images which are stored in the `post-content` container of each post.

The layout of a post looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-toolbar">
    <div class="post-date">date</div>
    <div class="signs">
      <div class="hearts">&hearts;</div>
      <div><img src="logo.png"></div>
      <div><img src="logo2.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-title">title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="post-content">
    <a href="#link"><img src="image.png"></a>
    <a href="#link"><img src="image.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a Javascript snippet which looks like this:

```
$('.hearts').live("click",function() {
    var amount = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("img").size();
    console.log(amount);        
});
```

At the moment the value of `amount` is `4`.

I'm sure the is a much nicer way to access the `.post-content` div with jQuery.

Comment: $("img","div.post-content") could be helpful. jQuery gives you the chance to use a context (the 2nd param) to what you search (first params).

Comment: @microspino that will get the images of all `post-content` divs, instead of for each post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.hearts').live("click",function() {
    var post = $(this).closest('.post'); // will find the first element with the class post up the DOM tree
    var amount = $('.post-content img', post).size();
    console.log(amount);        
});
```

BTW you should really look into [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and never use `.live()` again since live is [way slower](http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on) than delegate.

Or even better if you are on jQuery 1.7 or higher use `.on()`.

Comment: Another small performance improvement is to use the length instead of the size() method. Excerpt from documentation: The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call. Documentation URL: http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 2):

How about `$(this).parents(".post")` ?

```
$('.hearts').live("click",function() {
    var amount = $(this).parents(".post").children(".post-content").find("img").size();
    alert(amount);       
});
```

Comment: looks better! But I the value of *amount* is still 4. I only want to have the number of images that are in *post-content*